# Autolayout center y alignment strange behaviour when setting multiplier

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a helper view with dynamic height in my storyboard, this is a common practice to make layout responsive.

However, something strange happens when I introduce multipliers.

The blue button is aligned center y to the white view on the left:

[image]

Changing multiplier value into 0.5 should align the button to center of first half of the white view, at least it works this way when aligning to superview.

Instead I end up with sth like this:
[image]

The blue button height is equal to 0.05 times th height of the superview. The white view height is equal to 4 timees the height of the blue button

I have no idea what is the problem here that causes this weird alignment. I suspected it might be something with dynamic height value,  so I tried setting explicit height value but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: what is height of your white view ? and blue button ?

Comment: Blue button is 0.05 times the height of superview and the white view is 4 times the button's height

Comment: i need just height which you can see x , y , width , height . not multipliar. or if you have demo please upload it.

Comment: Ok, so since the simulated metrics is iPhone6, the button height is 30 and white view height is 120

Comment: try to set multipliar 0.25 to bluebutton .

Comment: which multiplier exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109140/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-dcdc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that if button is `Center Y` with multiplier `0.5`, than it should be positioned at the 1/4 of that white view.. No thats not worked like that .. lets check it with equation

multiplier works with this equation

```
 FirstItem.Attribute1 = (SecondItem.Attribute2 * Multiplier) + Constant
```

Your constraint is Button.Center Y = BlankView.center Y .. so this is how equation filled up

```
 Button.Center Y = (BlankView.center Y * 1) + 0
```

So the question is what is the value of BlankView.Center Y ...
answer is

```
 BlankView.Center Y = HeightOfSuperviewOFBlankView - (Y positionOFBlankView + (BlankViewHeight / 2))
 // in your case it would be 603 - (483 +(120/ 2)) = 543
```

Now move to Your equation `Center Y` with multiplier `0.5`

```
 Button.Center Y = (543 * 0.5) + 0  // 271.5
```

because of that your button position with Center Y is placed at

```
 Button.Center Y = 271.5 - (buttonHeight / 2) 
  // if we take buttonHeight = 30 than it should be 257.5 (approx 257)
```

I hope now you understand how center Y with multiplier works...

Comment: Alright, that's clear now why it works for positioning in regard to superview, and why it doesn't for view's located elsewhere! Your explanation is really great and clarify the confusion about setting multipliers!